# Classes added with jQuery not targetable with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a month switcher for a calendar with a smooth animation. I think i am pretty close,but just missing something here.

HTML:

```
<div id="monthscontainer">
    <div class="months">
        <h1 class="month1">JANUARY</h1>
        <h1 class="month2">FEBRUARY</h1>
        <h1 class="month3">MARCH</h1>
        <h1 class="month4">APRIL</h1>
        <h1 class="month5">MAY</h1>
        <h1 class="month6">JUNE</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#monthscontainer {
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
width: 840px;
height: 40px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.months {
position: relative;
left: 0px;
height: 40px;
width: 2000px;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.months.moved {
transform: translate(-240px,0px);
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.month1 {
float: left;
width: 240px;
text-align: left;
cursor: pointer;
color: #A2A2A2;
padding: 0px;
transition: color 1s ease;
}

.month2 {
float: left;
text-align: center;
width: 240px;
margin-left: 60px;
margin-right: 60px;
padding: 0px;
transition: color 1s ease;
}

.month3 {
float: left;
width: 240px;
text-align: right;
cursor: pointer;
color: #A2A2A2;
padding: 0px;
transition: color 1s ease;
}

.month4 {
float: left;
width: 240px;
text-align: right;
cursor: pointer;
color: #A2A2A2;
padding: 0px;
transition: color 1s ease;
}

.month5 {
float: left;
width: 240px;
text-align: right;
cursor: pointer;
color: #A2A2A2;
padding: 0px;
transition: color 1s ease;
}

.month6 {
float: left;
width: 240px;
text-align: right;
cursor: pointer;
color: #A2A2A2;
padding: 0px;
transition: color 1s ease;
}

.month1:hover, .month3:hover {
color: #484747;
transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Show #fireblockartists

        //<![CDATA[             
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.month3').on('click',slide);
            $('.month3').click(function(){
                $('.month3').on('click',slide);
            });
        });                     
        function slide() {
        $(".months").css({
                    left: function( index, value ) {
                        return parseFloat( value ) - 240;
                    }
                });
                $('.month2').addClass('month1');
                $('.month2').removeClass('month2');
                $('.month3').addClass('month2');
                $('.month3').removeClass('month3');
                $('.month4').addClass('month3');
                $('.month4').removeClass('month4');
                };

//]]>       
    </script>
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UzXuf/25/) to see a live demo of the problem.

I got 3 months in screen on the same time. They got the classes .month1 .month2 .month3 from left to right. When i click on a .month3 element, i want .month2 to become .month1, .month3 to become .month2, .month4 to become .month3, etc.

I want if you click on the most right month, it shifts them all 1 space to the left.

It works perfectly on the first click. On the second click, you could also click the middle month, and it would still trigger the animation. After the second click any following click just messes up completely.

When you try to click May, it wont fire the animation, even though when i inspect the element it has class .month3

It appears as if the newly applied classes arent rightly targeted by Jquery. What am i missing here?

Comment: Post relevant code in question. FYI, your issue comes from the fact you need to delegate event so class selector is accurate

Comment: Might you want this [__DEMO__](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/UzXuf/24/) Learn [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @Satpal That's exactly what i needed! Thank you so much. Thank you for the link to the explanation. I'll definetly will read that thoroughly! As far as i can see though you submitted the perfect solution as a comment, not an answer, so i can't accept it as an answer i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

**As you are manipulating event selector.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

Use

```
$(document).on('click', '.month3', slide);
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/UzXuf/24/)